# Quote code completion in VS2012 & ReSharper

Tags: razor, resharper, code-completion, visual-studio-2012

Given a view with the following Razor code:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
```

I want to add an Area parameter like so:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Manage" })
```

But when I start typing, this happens:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new object{Area = ""Manage"}) // broken double quote
```

How do I stop Visual Studio from completing the broken double quote so I don't have to play tetris for each link? Could ReSharper be causing this? I can't find the option for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type your code inside attribute, for example

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Manage" })">
```

then ReSharper can erroneously add a quote, resulting in "Manage"". This should be fixed in the last ReSharper 7.0 EAP releases. In previous versions, try turning off ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Editor -> Auto-insert pair brackets, parenthesis and quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I find that feature quite nifty but if you want it out of your way, then:
1. Go to "Tools" > "Options".
2. Expand the "Text Editor" node.
3. Expand the "HTML" node.
4. Uncheck the "Insert attribute value quotes when typing" field.

If you have ReSharper, then do this:
1. Go to ReSharper -> Options -> Intellisense -> General.
2. Check the Visual Studio option.

This will leave ReSharper out of the intellisense loop.

Comment: Yeah, but it's broken here. It does not complete on the first ", so I finish the word and upon typing the closing ", only then does it insert two quotes, which results in "Manage"".

Comment: I disabled this option, but it still does this. Must be ReSharper?

Comment: If you have ReSharper, then, I think that's the source of your sorrows. [Scott Hanselmann](http://twitter.com/shanselman/statuses/2263219917819904)